# Auto-generate for InfoPath Form using YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS-{AUTHOR_NAME}

Tags: workflow, list, document-library

May I know if a field (probably text field) in InfoPath 2007 form that can auto-generate the following format: YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS-{LIST_NAME}

where YYYYMMDD is the year, month, day
HHMMSS is the hour, minute, second
{AUTHOR-NAME} is the name of the person who is filling up the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested this formula inside my InfoPath 2007 form. Please try it and let me know if that is what you wanted.

> concat(substring(now(),1,4),substring(now(),6,2),substring(now(),9,2),"-",substring(now(),12,2),substring(now(),15,2),substring(now(),18,2),"-",userName())

The first 3 substring basically give you the YYYYMMDD, the next 3 substrings give you the HHMMSS while the last one - userName will give you the creator of the form.

Please also disable the field from modification and set the field as empty in the first place.